# Badge Proposal - *FacePalm* or "Doh!"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, voting

Although I have no doubt that this badge idea would get shot down, I find it amusing to think about.

Questions and answers would be able to accumulate special votes (almost like flagging a post) where each vote would be the equivalent to the voter facepalming. If you as a voter find the post jaw-dropping in the not-so-good way, facepalm at it.

Enough votes (say **10 or more** facepalms) would trigger a special badge of shameful humor. It wouldn't have any more negative side effects than temporary embarrassment for the user, but it could serve as a reminder to think before you post.

[The most famous facepalm in the world](http://media.photobucket.com/image/picard%20facepalm/seraphsephirot/picard-facepalm.jpg)

Comment: How do I vote this question for the facepalm badge?

Comment: +1, but only for *Facepalm*. We might have to add a Double Faceplam as well.

Comment: @Thomas Owens: That would be the "headdesk".

Comment: Pesto: You must vote for the badge first, then we can all *facepalm* at this together.

Comment: Would easily lead to new users being outcast by the system, who may be unaware of the humor involved and become discouraged.

Comment: @Ian: Well, that actually sounds like a positive then!

Comment: Ian: I would posit the argument that if you are capable of making a large number of the community bestow a facepalm badge on you, and you get discouraged to the point where you leave...then the community just was bettered as a whole. It not only prevents another amazing showing of dumbness, but prevents another thin-skinned user from whining about something else later on down the road.

Comment: I realize that it's useful to get rid of these people, but this is a business after all, and every user is valuable no matter how little or how vast their knowledge. Newer users are more likely to click ads :)

Comment: @Ian: And stupid users are more likely to make the good users who actually care about the site leave in mass numbers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We only want to encourage good behavior with badges, not negative behavior.

Funny concept though.

Comment: I had better get to work on a boring, pointless question to earn my Tumbleweed badge <grin>.

Comment: Tumbleweed is throwing those users who had very bad results with their question a little bone.

Answer (score 4):

Funny idea.

**But**, if anything, it should be a self-awarded badge. Otherwise it's mean.

Comment: If it's self-awarded, then it's kinda like the "Peer Pressure" badge.

Comment: *facepalm*       .

Comment: The point is that voting to give someone else a negative badge is borderline hostile.

Comment: If you make an insanely dumb post which X number of people thought was mindblowing, you'd probably get more discouraged from the downvotes it is sure to collect more than you would from the cheeky badge.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this what down-votes are for?

If you make it a badge, good or bad, people will want it. Basically you're just encouraged bad questions..

Answer (score 2):

```
............................................________
....................................,.-‘”...................``~.,
.............................,.-”...................................“-.,
.........................,/...............................................”:,
.....................,?......................................................,
.................../...........................................................,}
................./......................................................,:`^`..}
.............../...................................................,:”........./
..............?.....__.........................................:`.........../
............./__.(.....“~-,_..............................,:`........../
.........../(_....”~,_........“~,_....................,:`........_/
..........{.._$;_......”=,_.......“-,_.......,.-~-,},.~”;/....}
...........((.....*~_.......”=-._......“;,,./`..../”............../
...,,,___.`~,......“~.,....................`.....}............../
............(....`=-,,.......`........................(......;_,,-”
............/.`~,......`-...................................../
.............`~.*-,.....................................|,./.....,__
,,_..........}.>-._...................................|..............`=~-,
.....`=~-,__......`,.................................
...................`=~-,,.,...............................
................................`:,,...........................`..............__
.....................................`=-,...................,%`>--==``
........................................_..........._,-%.......`
...................................,
```

Comment: plz tell me why u downvoted mah facepalm i beleive it added lots 2 tihs discussion

Answer (score 0):

This would just encourage spiteful behavior from users who could cast a vote for such a badge.