# Exact number of Questions views over 1K

Tags: feature-request, questions, views

Can you add a feature to see the exact number of views for a question with views over 1,000?
 I have some questions that have over 2,000 views and would like to see how many more I need for the Notable question badge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click the question and you'll see the exact number on the right hand side.

Comment: Geez....How could I miss something like that?  Maybe I should ask for a feature to kick me in the butt for missing something so obvious.

Comment: Michael Kniskern: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1260/badge-proposal-facepalm-or-doh

Comment: I would also suggest a "Pimpsmack" badge.

Answer (score 2):

Open a question and then look to the right. Says, "Viewed" and under that, it says "x times."

P.S.-It appears to round up, so if you have 1,600 views, it says 2k, but you really have 400 more views to get to 2,000. This could lead to some confusion, if you're tracking it that closely.