# Would a "Facepalm" tag be useful/fun?

Tags: discussion, tags, humor

This has been asked before in reference to [badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1260/badge-proposal-facepalm-or-doh) but not about tags.

I asked [a question](https://serverfault.com/questions/773449/no-protocol-handler-valid-for-the-url-with-httpd-mod-proxy-balancer) a while back on Server Fault, and it turned out to be a facepalm-style problem (and solution). While it could technically be closed as "a simple typographical error", it has received many views and a few actual votes.

Is there any usefulness (or maybe playfulness?) in adding a "facepalm" tag, or would that more likely be abused to ridicule a question (or the person asking the question) rather than the typical downvote (or vote-to-close)?

Comment: That would be a [meta tag.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: We.  Hate.  Fun. ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I'm curious about the downvotes on the question. Was the question itself *not good* or are the downvotes indicating that nobody actually wants such a tag?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz In case you haven't been told yet: on Meta, downvotes are also used to express disagreement. People are probably just saying that they don't want this feature.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Thanks. In that case, should I withdraw the question by deleting it, or is it appropriate to leave it here as historical discussion?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz You can't delete it, because it has upvoted answers. A single post with many downvotes isn't a problem though. The only caveat - if your next posts _also_ get a lot of downvotes, you may want to consider if you're using MSE rightly.

Answer (score 7):

That tag would not be useful. Tags are supposed to help search; is there a point to searching for "in retrospect, that was foolish?"

It's also a bit of a meta-tag; facepalm for what? Password secrecy? Cables not connected?

Also, as you point out yourself, there would be a risk of the tag being used to humiliate people.

So, we don't need  this tag, and shouldn't want it.

Answer (score 3):

No. From the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging):

> #### What are tags, and how should I use them?
>
> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.

You can't be an expert in facepalm questions.

I know of one exception: [fun](/questions/tagged/fun), but Meta is different in many ways from a regular Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 3):

> ...or would that more likely be abused to ridicule a question...

Yes it would.

Cf. [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)